# Solr debug on Intellij idea with Tomcat

Tags: solr

I have been trying  to  debug solr 6.5 source with tomcat 8 with deploy .war my own artifact but I can' deploy give an 404 error and I put index.HTML in URL after /solr it work but not create instance. Plz help me for debug solr with tomcat using war deploy after changing source code

Comment: Tomcat is no longer supported as a Solr hosting platform.

Comment: Thx. Can I use older version of solr or tomcat

Comment: Solr 5/6 can't provide WAR deploy also but can I deploy and debug my own artifact war on tomcat

Comment: I dont want use of Remote debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr 6.2 on tomcat works. You can use my instructions [here](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Running-Solr-6-3-on-Tomcat-Help-Please-td4320874.html) to setup solr on tomcat. Unfortunately, solr 6.3+ doesn't work on tomcat and the solr team doesn't care.